# @Transactional marked as rollback only when @Transactional is used with child transactions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

I have a class that has a method that is marked as @Transactional. From that method, multiple methods marked also as @Transactional, are called.
So, hierarchically, it's like having a parent transaction with multiple child transactions.
The problem occurs when I call methods that are getting the data from the DB and then, in the end, I call a method that should store the data in the DB, then transaction commit fails and marks the Transaction with "`... transaction marked as rollback only ...`".

Code example:

Class A

```
class A{
    @Transactional
    public void parentMethod(){
        B b = B.getB();
        C c = c.getC();
        D d = new D();
        d.setB(b);
        d.setC(c);
        service.save(d);
    }
}
```

Class B

```
class B{
    @Transactional
    public B getB(){
        repository.getById(xxx);
    }
}
```

Class C

```
class C{
    @Transactional
    public C getC(){
        repository.getById(xxx);
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Transactional
public D save(D d){
    repository.save(d);
}
```

As you can see in the code above, when I call method `service.save(d);` I get "`... transaction marked as rollback only ...` " exception.
But, if I annotate all "**get**" subtransactions like this

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

I get expected results, e.g. the transactions are properly committed and no exception occurs.

Note: In my, real example, I have **multiple** "**save();**" methods and multiple "**get();**" methods before the final "**save();**" method.

Edit:
Take a look into this question: [Why get data and insert data from/in the DB is not working within the same 'parent' transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713565/why-get-data-and-insert-data-from-in-the-db-is-not-working-within-the-same-pare)

It's related to this problem. But the issue still persists.

Comment: There are no child transactions, there is only 1 single encompassing transaction. Only when using `REQUIRES_NEW` you have additional transactions. Now if 1 error occurs (doesn't matter where) the transaction should be rolledback.

Comment: It works that way. It rolls back everything if exception occurs..

Comment: No it doesn't, if there would be child transactions only the child transaction would rollback not the main transaction. Hence the behavior you see is actual proof that there is just 1 single transaction.

Comment: Since "fetch" transactions are separated from "insert" if exception occurs in any insert transaction it's going to rollback. In my main "parent" method, I do have rollbackFor in @Transactional annotation. So, that part works as expected.

Comment: As stated there are no separate transactions, the fact that you fetch or insert doesn't change that.

Comment: With Requires_New there are separated transactions. The question is, why do I have to have it separately? I was debugging it and the last insert was properly done but for some reason, even though there is no exception, it marks the transaction as rollback only on the commit.

Comment: With `REQUIRES_NEW` you have indeed separata transactions not in your first case. Something marks the tx as rollback, generally this is due to an exception (unless you are messing around things yourself), an exception being caught and not rethrown could be the culprit.

Comment: @M.Deinum I figured out that in my case, the problem could be using the method to retrieve the data from the DB and to insert the data into the DB within the same "parent" transaction.
Here is my second question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713565/why-get-data-and-insert-data-from-in-the-db-is-not-working-within-the-same-pare

Answer (score 0):

**Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW** : Don't use it because it creates a new transaction, and suspends the current transaction if one exists.

Use the default configuration of @Transaction: **Propagation.REQUIRED** that support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.

Comment: In this case, when only committed data are required it doesn't make any problem. But, I would like to avoid explicitly creating a new transaction. But, it just seems impossible because of the exception.. I don't know if table relation has something with it, but I don't think so..